# Trying to Compile Carabiner on windows using Powershell and MinGW MSYS. Having a gflags error in pthreads_rwlock_t

Tags: c++, windows, compiler-errors, mingw, gflags

From the beginning.

I want to compile for windows a tiny program called Carabiner aquired from this git repository: [Carabiner Git](https://github.com/brunchboy/carabiner)

It requires 2 main dependencies gflags and LiveLink. Not getting bogged down on what this program does, the instructions say to in git bash cd to you repository cloned directory and simply

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

It then says:

Carabiner uses CMake to manage its build process. Once again, from the top-level directory of your carabiner repository:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build .
```

Once the build completes you will find the executable in bin/Carabiner under the build directory.

Now there are a couple of hurdles i had to overcome which resulted in me using Powershell and getting the furthest.

First I have to employ a bit more than just cmake ..

```
cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles" ..
```

Then I had to install some more modules from MinGW to get some of the .h files, but 2 still were elusive. fnmatch.h I had to copy and paste it into many directories to find the 1 it was looking in and pthreads.h I managed to find the module I think.

So now these 2 are all part of gflags and it breaks the compiler there with no binaries created. The LiveLink doesn't even bother and the cache file ends abruptly.

The final error is pthreads_rwlock_t - failed and the cache gives it a value of 4, where I believe for success it should be 0.

If I then try to run cmake --build it says cannot read cache.

So here is the entire cmake process logs after getting the repositories:

```
    Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> cd..
PS C:\WINDOWS> cd..
PS C:\> cd users
PS C:\users> cd abstr
PS C:\users\abstr> cd workspace
PS C:\users\abstr\workspace> cd carabiner
PS C:\users\abstr\workspace\carabiner>
PS C:\users\abstr\workspace\carabiner> cd carabiner
PS C:\users\abstr\workspace\carabiner\carabiner> cd build
PS C:\users\abstr\workspace\carabiner\carabiner\build> cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles" ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for C++ include unistd.h
-- Looking for C++ include unistd.h - found
-- Looking for C++ include stdint.h
-- Looking for C++ include stdint.h - found
-- Looking for C++ include inttypes.h
-- Looking for C++ include inttypes.h - found
-- Looking for C++ include sys/types.h
-- Looking for C++ include sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for C++ include sys/stat.h
-- Looking for C++ include sys/stat.h - found
-- Looking for C++ include fnmatch.h
-- Looking for C++ include fnmatch.h - found
-- Looking for C++ include stddef.h
-- Looking for C++ include stddef.h - found
-- Check size of uint32_t
-- Check size of uint32_t - done
-- Looking for strtoll
-- Looking for strtoll - found
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Check size of pthread_rwlock_t
-- Check size of pthread_rwlock_t - failed
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/abstr/workspace/Carabiner/carabiner/build
PS C:\users\abstr\workspace\carabiner\carabiner\build> cmake --build
Usage: cmake --build <dir> [options] [-- [native-options]]
Options:
  <dir>          = Project binary directory to be built.
  --target <tgt> = Build <tgt> instead of default targets.
                   May only be specified once.
  --config <cfg> = For multi-configuration tools, choose <cfg>.
  --clean-first  = Build target 'clean' first, then build.
                   (To clean only, use --target 'clean'.)
  --use-stderr   = Ignored.  Behavior is default in CMake >= 3.0.
  --             = Pass remaining options to the native tool.
PS C:\users\abstr\workspace\carabiner\carabiner\build> cmake --build bin
Error: could not load cache
PS C:\users\abstr\workspace\carabiner\carabiner\build>
```

and here is the cache file:

```
    # This is the CMakeCache file.
# For build in directory: c:/Users/abstr/workspace/Carabiner/carabiner/build
# It was generated by CMake: C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe
# You can edit this file to change values found and used by cmake.
# If you do not want to change any of the values, simply exit the editor.
# If you do want to change a value, simply edit, save, and exit the editor.
# The syntax for the file is as follows:
# KEY:TYPE=VALUE
# KEY is the name of a variable in the cache.
# TYPE is a hint to GUIs for the type of VALUE, DO NOT EDIT TYPE!.
# VALUE is the current value for the KEY.

########################
# EXTERNAL cache entries
########################

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_AR:FILEPATH=C:/MinGW/bin/ar.exe

//Choose the type of build, options are: None(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS or
// CMAKE_C_FLAGS used) Debug Release RelWithDebInfo MinSizeRel.
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=

//Enable/Disable color output during build.
CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON

//CXX compiler
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe

//A wrapper around 'ar' adding the appropriate '--plugin' option
// for the GCC compiler
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_AR:FILEPATH=C:/MinGW/bin/gcc-ar.exe

//A wrapper around 'ranlib' adding the appropriate '--plugin' option
// for the GCC compiler
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_RANLIB:FILEPATH=C:/MinGW/bin/gcc-ranlib.exe

//Flags used by the compiler during all build types.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING=

//Flags used by the compiler during debug builds.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=-g

//Flags used by the compiler during release builds for minimum
// size.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=-Os -DNDEBUG

//Flags used by the compiler during release builds.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=-O3 -DNDEBUG

//Flags used by the compiler during release builds with debug info.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=-O2 -g -DNDEBUG

//Libraries linked by default with all C++ applications.
CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES:STRING=-lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32

//C compiler
CMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe

//A wrapper around 'ar' adding the appropriate '--plugin' option
// for the GCC compiler
CMAKE_C_COMPILER_AR:FILEPATH=C:/MinGW/bin/gcc-ar.exe

//A wrapper around 'ranlib' adding the appropriate '--plugin' option
// for the GCC compiler
CMAKE_C_COMPILER_RANLIB:FILEPATH=C:/MinGW/bin/gcc-ranlib.exe

//Flags used by the compiler during all build types.
CMAKE_C_FLAGS:STRING=

//Flags used by the compiler during debug builds.
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=-g

//Flags used by the compiler during release builds for minimum
// size.
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=-Os -DNDEBUG

//Flags used by the compiler during release builds.
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=-O3 -DNDEBUG

//Flags used by the compiler during release builds with debug info.
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=-O2 -g -DNDEBUG

//Libraries linked by default with all C applications.
CMAKE_C_STANDARD_LIBRARIES:STRING=-lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32

//Flags used by the linker.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during debug builds.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during release minsize builds.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during release builds.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during Release with Debug Info builds.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=

//Convert GNU import libraries to MS format (requires Visual Studio)
CMAKE_GNUtoMS:BOOL=OFF

//Install path prefix, prepended onto install directories.
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/Carabiner

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_LINKER:FILEPATH=C:/MinGW/bin/ld.exe

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM:FILEPATH=C:/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of modules.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during debug builds.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during release minsize builds.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during release builds.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during Release with Debug Info builds.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_NM:FILEPATH=C:/MinGW/bin/nm.exe

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_OBJCOPY:FILEPATH=C:/MinGW/bin/objcopy.exe

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_OBJDUMP:FILEPATH=C:/MinGW/bin/objdump.exe

//Value Computed by CMake
CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME:STATIC=Carabiner

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_RANLIB:FILEPATH=C:/MinGW/bin/ranlib.exe

//RC compiler
CMAKE_RC_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:/MinGW/bin/windres.exe

//Flags for Windows Resource Compiler.
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS:STRING=

//Flags for Windows Resource Compiler during debug builds.
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=

//Flags for Windows Resource Compiler during release builds for
// minimum size.
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=

//Flags for Windows Resource Compiler during release builds.
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=

//Flags for Windows Resource Compiler during release builds with
// debug info.
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of dll's.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during debug builds.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during release minsize builds.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during release builds.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during Release with Debug Info builds.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=

//If set, runtime paths are not added when installing shared libraries,
// but are added when building.
CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RPATH:BOOL=NO

//If set, runtime paths are not added when using shared libraries.
CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH:BOOL=NO

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of static libraries.
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during debug builds.
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during release minsize builds.
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during release builds.
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during Release with Debug Info builds.
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_STRIP:FILEPATH=C:/MinGW/bin/strip.exe

//If this value is on, makefiles will be generated without the
// .SILENT directive, and all commands will be echoed to the console
// during the make.  This is useful for debugging only. With Visual
// Studio IDE projects all commands are done without /nologo.
CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=FALSE

//Value Computed by CMake
Carabiner_BINARY_DIR:STATIC=C:/Users/abstr/workspace/Carabiner/carabiner/build

//Value Computed by CMake
Carabiner_SOURCE_DIR:STATIC=C:/Users/abstr/workspace/Carabiner/carabiner

//Value Computed by CMake
gflags_BINARY_DIR:STATIC=C:/Users/abstr/workspace/Carabiner/carabiner/build/gflags

//Value Computed by CMake
gflags_SOURCE_DIR:STATIC=C:/Users/abstr/workspace/Carabiner/carabiner/gflags

//Dependencies for target
gflags_nothreads_static_LIB_DEPENDS:STATIC=

//Dependencies for the target
gflags_static_LIB_DEPENDS:STATIC=general;-lpthread;


########################
# INTERNAL cache entries
########################

//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_AR
CMAKE_AR-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//This is the directory where this CMakeCache.txt was created
CMAKE_CACHEFILE_DIR:INTERNAL=c:/Users/abstr/workspace/Carabiner/carabiner/build
//Major version of cmake used to create the current loaded cache
CMAKE_CACHE_MAJOR_VERSION:INTERNAL=3
//Minor version of cmake used to create the current loaded cache
CMAKE_CACHE_MINOR_VERSION:INTERNAL=10
//Patch version of cmake used to create the current loaded cache
CMAKE_CACHE_PATCH_VERSION:INTERNAL=0
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE
CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//Path to CMake executable.
CMAKE_COMMAND:INTERNAL=C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe
//Path to cpack program executable.
CMAKE_CPACK_COMMAND:INTERNAL=C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cpack.exe
//Path to ctest program executable.
CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND:INTERNAL=C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/ctest.exe
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_AR
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_AR-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_RANLIB
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_RANLIB-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES
CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_COMPILER
CMAKE_C_COMPILER-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_COMPILER_AR
CMAKE_C_COMPILER_AR-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_COMPILER_RANLIB
CMAKE_C_COMPILER_RANLIB-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_FLAGS
CMAKE_C_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_STANDARD_LIBRARIES
CMAKE_C_STANDARD_LIBRARIES-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//Path to cache edit program executable.
CMAKE_EDIT_COMMAND:INTERNAL=C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake-gui.exe
//Executable file format
CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_FORMAT:INTERNAL=Unknown
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//Name of external makefile project generator.
CMAKE_EXTRA_GENERATOR:INTERNAL=
//Name of generator.
CMAKE_GENERATOR:INTERNAL=MSYS Makefiles
//Name of generator platform.
CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM:INTERNAL=
//Name of generator toolset.
CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET:INTERNAL=
//Have symbol pthread_create
CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_CREATE:INTERNAL=
//Have library pthreads
CMAKE_HAVE_PTHREADS_CREATE:INTERNAL=
//Have library pthread
CMAKE_HAVE_PTHREAD_CREATE:INTERNAL=1
//Have include pthread.h
CMAKE_HAVE_PTHREAD_H:INTERNAL=1
//Source directory with the top level CMakeLists.txt file for this
// project
CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY:INTERNAL=C:/Users/abstr/workspace/Carabiner/carabiner
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_LINKER
CMAKE_LINKER-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM
CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_NM
CMAKE_NM-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//number of local generators
CMAKE_NUMBER_OF_MAKEFILES:INTERNAL=2
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_OBJCOPY
CMAKE_OBJCOPY-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_OBJDUMP
CMAKE_OBJDUMP-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//Platform information initialized
CMAKE_PLATFORM_INFO_INITIALIZED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_RANLIB
CMAKE_RANLIB-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_RC_COMPILER
CMAKE_RC_COMPILER-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
CMAKE_RC_COMPILER_WORKS:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_RC_FLAGS
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//Path to CMake installation.
CMAKE_ROOT:INTERNAL=C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RPATH
CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RPATH-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH
CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STRIP
CMAKE_STRIP-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE
CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//Details about finding Threads
FIND_PACKAGE_MESSAGE_DETAILS_Threads:INTERNAL=[TRUE][v()]
//Have include fnmatch.h
HAVE_FNMATCH_H:INTERNAL=1
//Have include inttypes.h
HAVE_INTTYPES_H:INTERNAL=1
//Result of TRY_COMPILE
HAVE_RWLOCK:INTERNAL=FALSE
//Have include stddef.h
HAVE_STDDEF_H:INTERNAL=1
//Have include stdint.h
HAVE_STDINT_H:INTERNAL=1
//Have symbol strtoll
HAVE_STRTOLL:INTERNAL=1
//Have include sys/stat.h
HAVE_SYS_STAT_H:INTERNAL=1
//Have include sys/types.h
HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H:INTERNAL=1
//Have include unistd.h
HAVE_UNISTD_H:INTERNAL=1
//Result of TRY_COMPILE
HAVE_uint32_t:INTERNAL=TRUE
//CHECK_TYPE_SIZE: pthread_rwlock_t unknown
RWLOCK:INTERNAL=
//CHECK_TYPE_SIZE: sizeof(uint32_t)
uint32_t:INTERNAL=4
```

So for a noob, what the hell am I supposed to do here?

Many thanks

Robbie

**Additional Edit:**

Taking what S.M. has answered below into account I have since tried to cd.. out of the build directory and run cmake --build build from this effective root and I get the following (which dispalays 2 errors in gflags):

```
PS C:\users\abstr\workspace\carabiner\carabiner\build> cd..
PS C:\users\abstr\workspace\carabiner\carabiner> cmake --build build
[  7%] Building CXX object gflags/CMakeFiles/gflags_nothreads_static.dir/src/gflags.cc.obj
In file included from C:/Users/abstr/workspace/Carabiner/carabiner/build/gflags/include/gflags/config.h:115:0,
                 from c:/Users/abstr/workspace/Carabiner/carabiner/gflags/src/gflags.cc:90:
C:/Users/abstr/workspace/Carabiner/carabiner/gflags/src/windows_port.h: In function 'void setenv(const char*, const char*, int)':
C:/Users/abstr/workspace/Carabiner/carabiner/gflags/src/windows_port.h:80:13: error: ambiguating new declaration of 'void setenv(const char*, const char*, int)'
 inline void setenv(const char* name, const char* value, int) {
             ^~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\cstdlib:75:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\stdlib.h:36,
                 from C:/Users/abstr/workspace/Carabiner/carabiner/gflags/src/windows_port.h:56,
                 from C:/Users/abstr/workspace/Carabiner/carabiner/build/gflags/include/gflags/config.h:115,
                 from c:/Users/abstr/workspace/Carabiner/carabiner/gflags/src/gflags.cc:90:
c:\mingw\include\stdlib.h:837:30: note: old declaration 'int setenv(const char*, const char*, int)'
 __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW  int setenv( const char *__n, const char *__v, int __f )
                              ^~~~~~
make[2]: *** [gflags/CMakeFiles/gflags_nothreads_static.dir/src/gflags.cc.obj] Error 1
make[1]: *** [gflags/CMakeFiles/gflags_nothreads_static.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Also what has not been taken into account is that fact I stated in the 1st place, this hasn't finished making all the files to build. it should build files for both gflags and link and carabiner the build directory only has upto gflags and this is obviously incomplete as the errors occur and no binaries are created.

Here are screenshots of the 2 directories, the main with both gflags and link folders and the build folder with only gflags, which you see errors above.

[image: Main Directory]

[image: Build Directory]

Please someone try to replicate this on their own machine then amybe at least we can find what's missing and where.

Thanks again

Robbie

Comment: New problems are in gflags. Sorry, I will try to help you later, if nobody helps. I suppose the submodule gflags branch is buggy master instead of one of stable branches.

Comment: Any time to help on this yet?

Comment: I do not have Windows. The issue is Windows specific and is more related to Carabiner and not cmake or C++. Please report the issue on the github of the project.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find error where are no errors. You run `cmake --build bin` in wrong way. Since your working directory is already `build`, you should run `cmake --build .`

Comment: I get this if i do

Comment: please see my answer

Comment: Please read the manual and my answer carefully! The final dot must be in the command `cmake --build .`!

Comment: OK I've done that and it has the same issue as in my additional edit.... 7%  compiled with 2 errors in gflags: No binaries.

Comment: make[2]: *** [gflags/CMakeFiles/gflags_nothreads_static.dir/src/gflags.cc.obj] Error 1
make[1]: *** [gflags/CMakeFiles/gflags_nothreads_static.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2